# Accordion layout confusion

Tags: extjs4.1

I am using a Panel which has set of accordions Say first child , second child , third child.

i found when the panel has been instantiated the first child

will auto expand.  but when i remove the first child, the Accordion layout panel cannot auto expand child.

sorry for my poor English and unclear expression,can someone help and figure it out

```
var firstChild ={
        id:'first',
        title: 'first child',
        html: 'first child'
    };


var acc=    Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    title: 'Accordion layout',
    width: 300,
    height: 300,
    layout:'accordion',
    defaults: {
        bodyStyle: 'padding:15px'
    },
    layoutConfig: {
        titleCollapse: false,
        animate: false,
        activeOnTop: true,
        collapseFirst:true
    },
    items: [
        firstChild,
        {
        title: 'second child',
        html: 'second child'
    },{
        title: 'third child',
        html: 'third child'
    }],
    renderTo: 'demo'
});


acc.remove(Ext.getCmp("first"));
```

after remove the first child ,cannot auto expand child

new users aren't allowed to post images,here is the address

https://i.stack.imgur.com/im848.jpg
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1ze7.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You can just tell it to expand:

```
Ext.onReady(function() {

    var acc = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
        title: 'Accordion layout',
        width: 300,
        height: 300,
        layout: 'accordion',
        defaults: {
            bodyStyle: 'padding:15px'
        },
        layoutConfig: {
            titleCollapse: false,
            animate: false,
            activeOnTop: true,
            collapseFirst: true
        },
        items: [{
            id: 'first',
            title: 'first child',
            html: 'first child'
        }, {
            title: 'second child',
            html: 'second child'
        }, {
            title: 'third child',
            html: 'third child'
        }],
        renderTo: document.body
    });

    acc.remove('first');
    acc.items.first().expand();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a reported bug :

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?247396-4.1.3-Accordion-Layout-not-working-when-dynamically-adding-items